# add microseconds to a time in php

Tags: php, time

Here is the code i used to get the current time with microseconds,

```
 $time=date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s") . substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8);
```

I need to change the value in $time by adding some values in microsecond.Is possible to add microseconds to the time??
actually i need is need to create a simulator,Here i need to check how many executions are taking place in the interval of one second,and find how many microseconds needed for the execution.

Comment: there is a format character "u" for microseconds

Comment: Yep, @Pavel is right... microseconds were added in php 5.2.2

Comment: How to add a microsecond value to a vriable??is possible?

Comment: what do you mean "add a value to a variable"? concatenate strings? you are already doing it. you can add two floats - just convert the date to "seconds since 1970" and normalize the microtime. be aware of floating point arithmetic though.

Comment: $time=date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s") . substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8); I need to add  200 microseconds to $time.is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a fallback function for older versions like this. (It only works for the current time)

```
function udate($format, $utimestamp = null){
                if(is_null($utimestamp)){
                    $utimestamp = microtime(true);
                    $timestamp = floor($utimestamp);
                    $milliseconds = round(($utimestamp - $timestamp) * 1000000);
                    return date(str_replace("u",$milliseconds,$format), $timestamp);
                }else
                    return date($format, $utimestamp);
            }

echo udate('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
```